# Force exponent display of floats in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have some number in a `DataFrame` that are currently being displayed as: 0.000000. When I try:

```
set_printoptions(precision = 12)
```

I will get something like: 0.00000049100

Is there a way to display all/some of the numbers in this columns as exponents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch to engineering notation using "set_eng_float_format()", see also http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#console-output-formatting